# How can I skip running slow tests when running a particular test suite in PHPUnit, but still run all tests when I need full code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, phpunit

I have a single test suite that is marked at so in my PHPUnit configuration.  The test suite contains various many tests, and it also has database-intensive live database tests, which take a long time to complete.

In particular one of the tests takes over 2 seconds to complete (see below).

I want to *separate* running fast tests form slow tests, so that I can run the full slow but complete version of tests when I have more time, but in general I want to run the fast tests for my every-day needs, thereby omitting the slow tests when running the test suit.

How can I do this?

For the record, my phpunit.xml config is like so:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Crating">
        <directory>../module/Crating/test/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Command I use to run my test suite is like so:

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml --testsuite CratingCalc
```

One of the files in my `../module/Crating/test/` directory is `CrateRepositoryTest.php`.  It looks like so:

```
class CrateRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{

    function testCombine()
    {
        //mocked up hardcoded data
        $fake = new FakeCratingDataModel();

        //connection to real live database
        $real = new CratingDataModel();    

        /* 
         * Tests that verify mocked up data to match live data
         * Purpose to have them is to alert me when live database data or schema change
         */
        $this->assertEquals($fake->getContentsBySalesOrderNumber(7777), $real->getContentsBySalesOrderNumber(7777));
        $this->assertEquals($fake->getContentsByShopJobNumber(17167), $real->getContentsByShopJobNumber(17167));
        $this->assertEquals($fake->getNearCrating(20, 20, 20), $real->getNearCrating(20, 20, 20));
        $this->assertEquals($fake->getContentsByInquiryNumber(640, 2), $real->getContentsByInquiryNumber(25640, 2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups.

Normally, you can add annotations `@group small` or I have `@group ci` (just for things I'll run in a full CI environment).

Having small, medium or large tests is in fact so common, there are dedicated group annotations - `@small, @medium & @large`, and there are also settings for the phpunit.xml file that can also give a time-limit for each (and will kill, and fail them, if they take too long):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  ....
  timeoutForLargeTests="5"
  timeoutForMediumTests="2"
  timeoutForSmallTests="1"
  .... >
```

I have two ways to run my tests - the full version that does not exclude any groups (running over **1250 tests takes around 50 seconds**,  without coverage), and the faster tests that adds `--exclude-group ci,large,webtest` to the phpunit command, that can run 630 of the tests in less than **4 seconds**.